# How to check all the global templates when Word starts using macro/VBA?

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word, global

I have researched for a while and I couldn't find any answer for this problem..

Every single time I start Word only one custom global template is not being checked under "Document Templates".
I could check it manually but other staff will have the same problem as this is part of an automation I'm doing.

I wanted to know if there is a way to use VBA to make sure all the global templates are checked/visible.

I tried to use CommandBars but I received an invalid use of property error.

```
Application.CommandBars("WF_Assessment").Visible
```

Please see image attached for better reference.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Osf6n.jpg

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.templates and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.addins

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. I was using Application.Templates but it is actually an addin.

Follow the code that answers my previous question.

```
Sub test()
    Dim oAddin As AddIn
    
    For Each oAddin In AddIns
        oAddin.Installed = True
    Next oAddin 
End Sub
```

Comment: The simplest way of ensuring that global templates are loaded at startup is to install them in the Startup folder. That way they get loaded automatically.

Comment: Here is my page on the Word Startup folder. http://addbalance.com/word/startup.htm. I certainly would not want all available Add-Ins to be installed!